# How to add "ref" to a embedded nested react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

First of all, I'm new to React and second I believe I found some similar answers but my case might be a little different. I'm using a library called react-twitter-embed and it was very easy to implement but I see an error that I can't see to get rid of. The error says ***"A string ref, "embedContainer", has been found within a strict mode tree. String refs are a source of potential bugs and should be avoided. We recommend using useRef() or createRef() instead."***

Here's my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import "./TwitterFeed.css";

import { TwitterTimelineEmbed } from "react-twitter-embed";

function TwitterFeed() {

  return (
    <div className="twitterFeed">
        <TwitterTimelineEmbed
          sourceType="profile"
          screenName="KeypointIntel"
          options={{ height: 400 }}
        />
    </div>
  )
}

export default TwitterFeed
```

Comment: Seems like this is an issue of the library, not of your code. The issue is located [here](https://github.com/saurabhnemade/react-twitter-embed/blob/fe4fbd4779621434a36213144576a3d5ec143a9e/src/components/TwitterTimelineEmbed.js#L187). There is already an [issue](https://github.com/saurabhnemade/react-twitter-embed/issues/71) created. You could +1 () the issue to signify that you have the same problem.

Comment: @3limin4t0r Thank you so much for looking into this issue. Cheers!